# Google Spreadscheet COUNTIF in ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a work/project overview, but I'm stuck. Hope you guys can help me out.

[image]

The countif formula checks for how much times the criteria is the same. As you can see in the image, Gregor has worked 1 time on Project A. The answer is 1. That's correct. But now I want to check the hours worked on it. So the answer should be 8.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I recommend using `countifs` and `sumifs` to handle multiple conditions. They make unnecessary your workaround with joining the columns.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar function `SUMIF()`, which sums the matches instead of counting them.

Comment: Could you give me an example or just change mines

Comment: No, this is not a coding service. Read the help on COUNTIF and on SUMIF, and it should be straightforward and simple to do.

Comment: Will try it - thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `countifs` and `sumifs` to handle multiple conditions. They make unnecessary your workaround with joining the columns. Example:

```
=sumifs(E:E, B:B, "Gregor", C:C, "A")
```

This means: add all values from column E where B is "Gregor" and C is "A".